# Magento pass extra info to payment gateway

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am trying to follow http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based to build a payment gateway.

Everything is ok. But I need to pass a digital signature to payment gateway.

I think I should add it in the class Excellence_Pay_Model_Pay assignData($data)

```
info = $this->getInfoInstance();
        $info->setCcType($data->getCcType())
            ->setCcOwner($data->getCcOwner())
            ->setCcLast4(substr($data->getCcNumber(), -4))
            ->setCcNumber($data->getCcNumber())
            ->setCcCid($data->getCcCid())
            ->setCcExpMonth($data->getCcExpMonth())
            ->setCcExpYear($data->getCcExpYear())
            ->setCcSsIssue($data->getCcSsIssue())
            ->setCcSsStartMonth($data->getCcSsStartMonth())
            ->setCcSsStartYear($data->getCcSsStartYear())
            ->setCcsignature($data->getCcsignature());
```

I have added one more field : ->setCcsignature($data->getCcsignature());

But I am not able to retrieve it on  capture() or callApi() function. It is empty all the time. I thought ->setSsignature will use php magic set function, isn't it?

Any hint and advise will be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to check if the value is being set or not by using $info->getCcsignature().  After the value has been set, if it is being passed on to capture() or callApi() function.  You just need to follow the basic steps of debugging. echo-die, echo-die and so on.  Good Luck.